# what's happening between webrowser and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, request

How is transformed and passed from a http request to the one that hit routes.rb file. I know about `webrick`, but I can't find where is the `webrick`'s code

Answer (score 1):

This is the path your request is going through when using Webrick:

host -> port -> sockets -> connections -> packets

This is the hierarchy of containers. Host is localhost and the port 
is either 80 (invisible) or 3000 (explicit).

Webrick "listens" at a port until a client creates a socket and makes a
connection. The connection then persists, and another client can connect 
at the same port.

A connection is like a virtual pair of wires. The server and client 
communicate by sending and receiving messages, and the connection protocol cuts these 
up into packets. Because Webrick only deals with one packet at a time, and because the connection layer stores the actual server and client
information, Webrick can handle multiple browsers at the same time.

You can read more [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html)